# Aptana Studio 3 - All SFTP connections are failing

Tags: aptana, sftp

All of a sudden all of my SFTP connection are failing in Aptana Studio 3. They've worked fine for several months until today. The same connection work fine in my Smart FTP program using SFTP.

The only change made somewhat recently (a couple of weeks ago) was installing a GIT client in Aptana. I've since uninstalled it but I still can open my SFTP connections (FTP works fine).

The popup error is 'Fetching children failed' has encountered a problem. Establishing SFTP connection failed: /

Please, any help is appreciated - I cannot get any work done now :(

LOG FILE:

!ENTRY com.aptana.ui 4 0 2013-06-24 12:37:48.907
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Establishing SFTP connection failed: /
    at com.aptana.filesystem.secureftp.internal.SFTPConnectionFileManager.connect(SFTPConnectionFileManager.java:314)
    at com.aptana.core.io.vfs.BaseConnectionFileManager.testOrConnect(BaseConnectionFileManager.java:971)
    at com.aptana.core.io.vfs.BaseConnectionFileManager.testOrConnect(BaseConnectionFileManager.java:962)
    at com.aptana.core.io.vfs.BaseConnectionFileManager.childInfos(BaseConnectionFileManager.java:207)
    at com.aptana.core.io.efs.VirtualFile.childInfos(VirtualFile.java:69)
    at com.aptana.ide.ui.io.FileSystemUtils.childInfos(FileSystemUtils.java:128)
    at com.aptana.ide.ui.io.navigator.FileSystemWorkbenchAdapter.fetchFileSystemChildren(FileSystemWorkbenchAdapter.java:286)
    at com.aptana.ide.ui.io.navigator.FileSystemWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(FileSystemWorkbenchAdapter.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: com.aptana.ide.core.io.PermissionDeniedException: /
    at com.aptana.filesystem.secureftp.internal.SFTPConnectionFileManager.throwWrappedException(SFTPConnectionFileManager.java:506)
    at com.aptana.filesystem.secureftp.internal.SFTPConnectionFileManager.changeCurrentDir(SFTPConnectionFileManager.java:476)
    at com.aptana.filesystem.secureftp.internal.SFTPConnectionFileManager.connect(SFTPConnectionFileManager.java:283)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPException: 3 Permission denied
    at com.enterprisedt.net.j2ssh.sftp.SftpSubsystemClient.a(SftpSubsystemClient.java:1103)
    at com.enterprisedt.net.j2ssh.sftp.SftpSubsystemClient.openDirectory(SftpSubsystemClient.java:448)
    at com.enterprisedt.net.j2ssh.SftpClient.cd(SftpClient.java:338)
    at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.ssh.SSHFTPClient.chdir(SSHFTPClient.java:1633)
    at com.aptana.filesystem.secureftp.internal.SFTPConnectionFileManager.changeCurrentDir(SFTPConnectionFileManager.java:470)
    ... 10 more
!SUBENTRY 1 com.aptana.filesystem.secureftp 4 0 2013-06-24 12:37:48.908
!MESSAGE Establishing SFTP connection failed: /
!STACK 0
com.aptana.ide.core.io.PermissionDeniedException: /
    at com.aptana.filesystem.secureftp.internal.SFTPConnectionFileManager.throwWrappedException(SFTPConnectionFileManager.java:506)
    at com.aptana.filesystem.secureftp.internal.SFTPConnectionFileManager.changeCurrentDir(SFTPConnectionFileManager.java:476)
    at com.aptana.filesystem.secureftp.internal.SFTPConnectionFileManager.connect(SFTPConnectionFileManager.java:283)
    at com.aptana.core.io.vfs.BaseConnectionFileManager.testOrConnect(BaseConnectionFileManager.java:971)
    at com.aptana.core.io.vfs.BaseConnectionFileManager.testOrConnect(BaseConnectionFileManager.java:962)
    at com.aptana.core.io.vfs.BaseConnectionFileManager.childInfos(BaseConnectionFileManager.java:207)
    at com.aptana.core.io.efs.VirtualFile.childInfos(VirtualFile.java:69)
    at com.aptana.ide.ui.io.FileSystemUtils.childInfos(FileSystemUtils.java:128)
    at com.aptana.ide.ui.io.navigator.FileSystemWorkbenchAdapter.fetchFileSystemChildren(FileSystemWorkbenchAdapter.java:286)
    at com.aptana.ide.ui.io.navigator.FileSystemWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(FileSystemWorkbenchAdapter.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.FTPException: 3 Permission denied
    at com.enterprisedt.net.j2ssh.sftp.SftpSubsystemClient.a(SftpSubsystemClient.java:1103)
    at com.enterprisedt.net.j2ssh.sftp.SftpSubsystemClient.openDirectory(SftpSubsystemClient.java:448)
    at com.enterprisedt.net.j2ssh.SftpClient.cd(SftpClient.java:338)
    at com.enterprisedt.net.ftp.ssh.SSHFTPClient.chdir(SSHFTPClient.java:1633)
    at com.aptana.filesystem.secureftp.internal.SFTPConnectionFileManager.changeCurrentDir(SFTPConnectionFileManager.java:470)
    ... 10 more

Comment: Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. I'm at my wits end here. I've worked on trying to fix this for the last 11 hours with no luck. I've even completely removed Aptana several times and reinstalled. FTP works in Aptana but not SFTP. However, SFTP works fine in another client (Smart FTP).

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing exactly the same issue so you're not alone. On the face of it the error seems to be suggesting a permissions issue, incorrect username and password for example. However, simply switching to FTP without changing any of the other details seems to allow connections to be made.

As with you, if I try the same SFTP settings in Cyberduck the connection is made.

I've had a good look through the Aptana support area and cannot find any reference to this issue. I have raised an issue on their JIRA system - https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-7936

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue for a while now and finally was able to connect if I unchecked the "validate certificate" (the ssl cert didn't match url or whatever) and actually added the @domainname.com to the end of the username field (which wasn't required when I used Cyberduck. so username: username **@domain.com** rather than just **username**. If that doesn't work, I'd suggest toying around with the settings a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this topic is old, it is still valid. When Aptana Studio tries to connect with SFTP, the server returns "kex protocol error: type 30 seq 1 [preauth]". Newer OpenSSH versions do not support the message type used by Aptana Studio anymore.

Since Aptana Studio ist not really actively developed anymore, you have to workaround. One solution would be to use FTP or FTPS instead.

Another suggested solution I found is to change the allowed key exchange algorithms at the remote server, as mentioned in https://nikinuryadin.wordpress.com/2015/05/19/aptana-studio-3-sftp-key-exchange/ and to add diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 to the "KexAlgorithms" at sshd_config.

But be aware that there are reasons why the old key exchange algorithms are no longer supported by default.